# get database name from mysql connection string?

Tags: javascript, node.js, regex, ecmascript-6, substring

Is there any way to get Database Name from MySql connection string?

For example, MySQL data string can be any of the two types.

i). `mysql://root:password@localhost/test`

ii). `mysql://root:password@localhost/test?debug=true&charset=BIG5_CHINESE_CI&timezone=-0700`

So how to get the database name like 'test'(in this case). From any one of the two above given strings?

Thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If regex is an option, this is an approach:

```
var regex = /\/([^\/\?]+)(?:\?.+)?$/;

"mysql://root:password@localhost/test".match(regex)[1]

"mysql://root:password@localhost/test?debug=true&charset=BIG5_CHINESE_CI&timezone=-0700".match(regex)[1]
```

Answer (score 3):

Node.js's built-in URL module will be able to reliably parse your example connection strings.

```js
var url = require('url')
var parsed = url.parse('mysql://root:password@localhost/test?debug=true&charset=BIG5_CHINESE_CI&timezone=-0700')
var databaseName = parsed.pathname
```